# Convert time interval from text to number and grouping by customer time interval

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot

I have some data grouped by quarter hour, and this column is a text format. I want to group the data by customer time intervals, like hourly, or 6am-9am etc. How can I do this in Power Query Editor for use with Power Pivot/Excel?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you most of the way there

right click and split the column on the - character

Transform the desired column wth something like the hour function and change the code from

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Quarter Hour.2", Time.Hour, Int64.Type}})
```

to

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Quarter Hour.2", each Time.From(Number.Round(Number.From(Time.From(_))*(24*60/15))/(24*60/15)), type time}})
```

to round to nearest desired number of minutes, here I am using closest 15 minutes

From there just filter using drop downs for the desired time ranges and group whatever you want

sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Quarter Hour", type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Quarter Hour", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Quarter Hour.1", "Quarter Hour.2"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Quarter Hour.1", type time}, {"Quarter Hour.2", type time}}),
#"Extracted Hour" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Quarter Hour.2", 
    each Time.From(Number.Round(Number.From(Time.From(_))*(24*60/15))/(24*60/15))
, type time}})
in  #"Extracted Hour"
```

Comment: Did this work for you?